# How do I define environments for db:environment:set?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5.1, postgres-9.6

I'm trying to set my database environment to `staging` but I get this error:

```
$ bin/rails db:environment:set RAILS_ENV=staging
rails aborted!
ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified: database configuration does not specify adapter
/Users/bfruitman/workspace/hired/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/bfruitman/workspace/hired/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/bfruitman/workspace/hired/bin/spring:14:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:environment:set => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I already have an entry in `database.yml`:

```
staging:
  <<: *heroku
```

But that's obviously not good enough. Where should I be defining `staging`?

Comment: Can you show the rest of `database.yml`? Specifically, make sure you have set up an alias for the heroku section like this: `heroku: &heroku`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to change your db environment is with psql:

```
update ar_internal_metadata set value = 'staging' where key = 'environment';
```

Replace `staging` with whatever environment you want to use.

Answer (score -2):

You probably need to add the file: `config/environments/staging.rb`, it is not included by default, I usually start by copying my production.rb and then making any staging specific changes (if needed).

`cp config/environments/production.rb config/environments/staging.rb`